# Delphi & ADO - How to get value of ID column after Post?

Tags: sql-server, delphi, c++builder, ado

To add a new record in MS SQL database table I used a `TADOTable` component and it's `Append` and `Post` methods.

My table contains `ID` column (`PK, auto-increment`) and after I execute `Post` method, I need to know what `ID` value is assigned in the new record.

How to do it?

Comment: Eventually the value will be read back into the TADOTable automatically, but not yet in OnAfterInsert. You do however get a dataset parameter to that event, in which the new value can already be read from the parameters.

Comment: In general I would recommend to use TADOQuery over TADOTable. Not for this reason, but because it allows you to specify the exact query for the data that you want, which in most cases will make your application faster and/or more efficient for your database.

Answer (score 2):

Use **[`TDOQuery`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/Data.Win.ADODB.TADOQuery)** component with **[`OUTPUT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#examples)** clause to insert the data and return the `ID`s as

```
AQ.Close;
AQ.SQL.Clear;
AQ.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO Table (Col1, Col2) OUTPUT INSERTED.ID VALUES (:Param1, :Param2)');
AQ.Parameters.ParamByName('Param1').Value:= SomeValue;
AQ.Parameters.ParamByName('Param2').Value:= SomeValue;
AQ.Open;
```

Note that you need to use **[`Open`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.Open)** method instead of **[`ExecSQL`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/Data.Win.ADODB.TADOQuery.ExecSQL)** to return the results.

You can also use **[`SCOPE_IDENTITY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** and you will need to create a parameter to return the value for you, and assign `pdReturnValue` to the `Direction` of that parameter

```
Var InsertedID: Integer;
...
AQ.Close;
AQ.SQL.Clear;
AQ.SQ.Add('INSERT INTO Table (Col1, Col2) VALUES (:Param1, :Param2);');
AQ.SQL.Add('SET :ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()');
AQ.Parameters.ParamByName('Param1').Value:= SomeValue;
AQ.Parameters.ParamByName('Param2').Value:= SomeValue;
AQ.Parameters.ParamByName('ID').Direction:= pdReturnValue 
AQ.ExecSQL;
InsertedID:= AQ.Parameters.ParamByName('ID').AsInteger;
```

---

<sub>**AQ** in the example is a `TADOQuery`.</sub>